# Append ticket number to all commit messages in git history local and remote

Tags: git, shell

How could I append the ticket number "TIX-321" to all commit messages already existing in my branch test_branch, within a bash script?

It would amount to looping thru all commits and for each git amend commit.

I would like to do it automatically within a shell script, I do not want to do it manually with an interactive rebase.

Comment: You need to force that by adding commit hook to validate against the ticket entered. In Bitbukcet it is a plugin.

Comment: ok, but throughout all history of the commits?

Comment: Note that it's physically impossible to change any existing commit. What you would do with a script like this is *replace* all the existing commits with new (and supposedly improved) commits. You must then convince everyone using the old repository to switch over to the new and (supposedly) improved repository. If you can do that, it's easy; if you can't do that, it's literally impossible.

Comment: As long as "everyone" is "just you", use the method on VonC's answer (`git filter-repo`). Note that a *message* filter applies only to the *message*, not to any committed files.

Comment: It will be applied to new commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an interractive rebase of your branch (assuming it comes from `main`)

```
git switch test_branch
git rebase -i $(git merge-base --fork-point main)
```

In the editor automatically opened, you can then change all commit messages, save and quit.
That will rewrite each commit of your branch, which you will have to force push (make sure anyone working on that branch is aware).

You can use the same range of commits to do so programmatically, using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), using its new [`--replace-message` option](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/commit/129a3bcb8b3b8fa810a7bd48f9e8cd541c62cf94).
As with [replace-text](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/129a3bcb8b3b8fa810a7bd48f9e8cd541c62cf94/Documentation/git-filter-repo.txt#L158), `regex:` is supported, so you can use an `expression.txt` file with:

```
regex:(.*)$==>TIX-321 \1
```

And the command:

```
git filter-repo --replace-message expressions.txt $(git merge-base --fork-point main)..test_branch
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to do it automatically within a shell script, I do not want to do it manually :)

Comment: @uniXVanXcel OK. That would be using `git filter-repo`.

Comment: I am actually using it, so great point; I do not see the command though to do so; can you help me out, I want to amend all commits messages

Comment: @uniXVanXcel I have edited the answer with the actual command.

Comment: Hmm this would append the new message to all parts of the file, I only want it for the commit message... thanks though

Comment: @uniXVanXcel I don't understand: `--replace-message` is for the commit message, not the file content. Meaning it does change what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To append a paragraph containing just the ticket number to the message of every commit in your repo, install [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), then run this in a clone of your repository:

```bash
git filter-repo --message-callback 'return message + b"\n\nTIX-321"'
```

This will, for example, change this commit message:

> OBS-12: fix frobulator parsing
>
> Make the parser able to handle the non-numeric IDs returned by the Zob API.

To this:

> OBS-12: fix frobulator parsing
>
> Make the parser able to handle the non-numeric IDs returned by the Zob API.
>
> TIX-321

#### Why these arguments for `git filter-repo`

The [`--message-callback` flag](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo#--message-callback) takes a string that will be interpreted as Python that returns the new commit message given a `message` bytestring. The callbacks above concatenate the `message` bytestring and another bytestring. (In Python, you will get an error if you try to concatenate a bytestring `b"…"` and a string `"…"`.)

`--message-callback` can easily handle multi-line commit messages, unlike  [`--replace-message`](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo#--replace-message). `--replace-message` takes the path to a file with expressions, but a `regex:` expression in that file can only return a string based on each line of the commit message. `--message-callback` can examine and edit the whole commit message.

#### Examples of other commit message templates

##### Add the ticket to the beginning of every message

```bash
git filter-repo --message-callback 'return b"TIX-321: " + message'
```

Changes this commit message:

> Fix frobulator parsing
>
> Make the parser able to handle the non-numeric IDs returned by the Zob API.

To this:

> TIX-321: Fix frobulator parsing
>
> Make the parser able to handle the non-numeric IDs returned by the Zob API.

##### Leave the message unchanged if the ticket number is already mentioned

```bash
git filter-repo --message-callback 'return message if "TIX-321" in message else message + b"\n\nTIX-321"'
```

Will not modify this commit message:

> TIX-321: fix frobulator parsing
>
> Make the parser able to handle the non-numeric IDs returned by the Zob API.